# How to setup OpenVPN in ubuntu 16.04 desktop over a Proxy server?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, proxy, openvpn

My college provides Internet through a proxy server, I need to login my username and password to access internet.

I have seen installation methods of openVPN but they don't talk about how to configure it over a proxy server.

How can I configure OpenVPN to use my proxy and login credentials to connect to VPN?

Comment: @Arronical: There is actually, but it's still in-development and thus off-topic here.

Comment: Though the OP could possibly be mistaken about their version number.

Comment: So, you're trying to setup an openVPN server on your university network, so you can remotely connect back into the network, while away?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to blocked sites, like YouTube, and all social networking sites, I want OpenVPN because my proxy firewall is not letting me to make a SSH Tunnel to my EC2 instance at Amazon Web Services. @bc2946088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to remote server through proxy by openvpn command line options like this:

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/config-file.ovpn --http-proxy proxy_server_addr port
```

Or if proxy uses socks:

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/config-file.ovpn --socks-proxy proxy_server_addr port
```

If proxy server requiers authentication, the console prompt you to enter your username and password. otherwise you can create a file that contains username and password in each line and append filename to the command:

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/config-file.ovpn --http-proxy proxy_server_addr port authfile
```

Comment: Getting Error : Options error: I'm trying to parse "/home/ags/vpn/vpnbook-us1-tcp80.ovpn" as an --option parameter but I don't see a leading '--'

Comment: Got it working with **sudo openvpn --config  /path/to/config-file.ovpn --http-proxy proxy_server_addr port** , but why --config?

Comment: if you specify an additional option after the config file, you must write `--config` before config file. :)

Comment: When i set sock-proxy then my vm is stopped and i have to reboot the vm to start working..
i want to route all openvpn traffic through Tor which is installed on the server